# Dependency property default value not being overriden

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I am trying to override the value of a dependency property but it doesn't seem to be working.

In my Xaml code I have a button with the following CommandParameter :

```
CommandParameter="{Binding State,Mode=OneWay}
```

and here I declare my dependency property:

```
public class MyStateControl : UserControl
{
  public MyStateControl()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  public string State
  {
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "State", typeof(string), typeof(MyStateControl),new   PropertyMetadata("DEFAULT"));
}
```

and then here I try to get that value to use it, after overriding it. 
When I press the button, onMyCommandExecuted gets called. and the value of obj is "DEFAULT"

```
public class MyAdvancedStateControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public MyAdvancedStateControl()
  {
   MyStateControl.StateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyAdvancedStateControl), new PropertyMetadata("Successfully overriden"));
  }

  private void onMyCommandExecuted(object obj)
  {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? If so, what's the best way to override the value of a dependency property?
And would it be possible/ probably better to set the default value as a variable that I can then change easily from MyAdvancedStateControl?
Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Your `MyStateControl` defines a dependency property and you set the `CommandParameter` to the value of this one. How is the `MyAdvancedStateControl` supposed to involved in this?

Comment: So what's the releationship between MyAdvancedStateControl and MyStateControl? How are they related to each other? And where is the command defined=

Comment: MyAdvancedStateControl is the ViewModel, the command is defined in it

Comment: Then you should define State as CLR property in the view model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the constructor of `MyAdvancedStateControl` `static`.

> Dependency property metadata should be overridden before the property
>   system uses the dependency property. This equates to the time that
>   specific instances are created using the class that registers the
>   dependency property. **Calls to OverrideMetadata should only be
>   performed within the static constructors** of the type that provides
>   itself as the forType parameter of this method, or through similar
>   instantiation. Attempting to change metadata after instances of the
>   owner type exist will not raise exceptions, but will result in
>   inconsistent behaviors in the property system.

From [DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public static MyAdvancedStateControl()
{
    MyStateControl.StateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyStateControl), new PropertyMetadata("Successfully overriden"));
}
```