# Mahapps SplitButton modifies SelectedItem while removing another element

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using an ObservableCollection with a SplitButton and I have detected that SelectedItem is modified while removing another element.

**Status** -> Collection = [A, B, C] and Selected = B

**Action** -> Remove(C)

**Result** -> Collection = [A, B] and Selected = A

Delete code:

```
Datacollection.ToList().Where(x => x.field > 5).ToList().ForEach(y => Datacollection.Remove(y));
```

XAML code:

```
<mah:SplitButton ItemsSource="{Binding Datacollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"/>
```

I expect Selected not to be modified if the removed item is different to the Selected. If I use Combobox instead of SplitButton, I dont have this problem.

Comment: Is it always first item selected after delete? Try to set breakpoint in `Selected` property setter, you may find who is changing it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug, see [Fix SplitButton SelectedIndex and SelectedItem #1798](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/1798/commits/9b07c07dc2d4e02758c35d4d3a9f443e43d686f9)

As workaround you could try to override default value for `SplitButton.SelectedIndexProperty`.

```
SplitButton.SelectedIndexProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SplitButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(-1));
```

Put it to the some static constructor, which will be called. See also [Dependency property default value not being overriden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998844/7713750).

Comment: I tried this, but it didnt work. I mark the solution as useful because I think there is some kind of bug in Mahapps. Finally, I am using a Combobox control instead of SplitButton.